# Aggregate Clouds not publishing in RGBDSLAM by Felix Endres

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of all of the topics published by RGBDSLAM (I think the correct way to see this is rostopic info /rgbdslam), /rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds seem to be what I'm looking for, but I have encountered a couple problems with this:

With /rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds, Its not publishing anyting when I am doing echo,I am not getting anything.

And is rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds the right topic to subscribe to,If I want full map in rviz to be used by navigation stack?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226106/aggregate-clouds-not-publishing-in-rgbdslam-by-felix-endres/) by [uzair_azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/25812/uzair_azhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since this takes a lot of computation for large maps, you have to trigger it. There's a gui option for sending the model and a ros service call that you can use. See the README -> Usage without GUI

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair_azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/25812/uzair_azhar/) on 2016-02-16**:
Thanks.One more thing, how to track kinect in gui(localization) while mapping and how to use it for path planning and obstacle avoidance.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-02-17**:
The latest pose is send out on the `/tf` topic. For online path planning and obstacle avoidance you'd probably get better answers from other people. And it depends greatly on your application. Checkout the existing questions and answers or post your own question for your specific use case.

**Comment by [j](https://answers.ros.org/users/34557/j/) on 2018-04-10**:
I have also been unable to get the aggregate_cloud to publish. I have tried using the `rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui send_all` command, however it only publishes the `online_coulds` and none of the other pointclouds. Any recommendations for getting it to publish the aggregate_cloud?